# Lottie error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse composition

Tags: java, android, lottie

Trying to integrate Lottie animation file into my Android Studio project.I have done and rechecked all the integration steps.

1. in build.gradle I added the latest version:

   ```
   implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.1.0"
   ```
2. brought the exported JSON file (from lottiefiles.com) into the res/raw folder. (I also tried the /asset folder but it still does not work)
3. in one of my layout files I refer to it with:

   ```
   <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
      android:id="@+id/animationView"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/confetti"
      app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
      app:lottie_loop="true"
   />
   ```

Weirdly, the Design Interface shows the error:

> Unexpected resource type: raw.
> Expected: string.

This error is not shown in the XML Interface code, but only in the Design Interface.

The image showing the layout error when using Lottie file:
[image: The image showing the layout error when using Lottie file]

Consequently, when running the project the app crashes and I get this error:

```
--------- beginning of crash
 `2021-09-11 01:17:13.538 13479-13479/com.intelligentemo.dialogoengkor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.intelligentemo.dialogoengkor, PID: 13479
    **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse composition**
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$1.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:79)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$1.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:72)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$3.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:96)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$3.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:89)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.notifyFailureListeners(LottieTask.java:162)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.access$200(LottieTask.java:28)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask$1.run(LottieTask.java:137)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     **Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0**
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1384)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.LayerParser.parse(LayerParser.java:136)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.LottieCompositionMoshiParser.parseLayers(LottieCompositionMoshiParser.java:120)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.LottieCompositionMoshiParser.parse(LottieCompositionMoshiParser.java:86)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonReaderSyncInternal(LottieCompositionFactory.java:390)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonReaderSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:383)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonInputStreamSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:313)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonInputStreamSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:306)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawResSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:269)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory$3.call(LottieCompositionFactory.java:234)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory$3.call(LottieCompositionFactory.java:229)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

Have checked so many resources and tutorials, but no one seem to have had this issue yet...

Comment: Were you able to find a way around?

Answer (score 0):

```
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse composition**
```

Due to these codes, try to **Replace** it

```
app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/confetti"
```

**with**

```
app:lottie_fileName="confetti.json"
```

Lottie looks by default in the `src/main/assets` folder.